# NUXT3 does not create index.html with nuxt generate

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

the project is run locally. but when the pipeline is build, 403 is loaded on the test server. index.html it is not created using `nuxt generate`.
I do not know exactly when the error appeared, but I did not install any new libraries. when using `nuxt build`, several errors appear in the css of the swiper nuxt and vuestic-ui libraries. but these libraries have been installed since the beginning of the project.
nuxt.config.ts

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({

    css: ["assets/style.css", "vuestic-ui/styles/essential.css", "assets/font/stylesheet.css"],

    modules: ['nuxt-swiper', '@pinia/nuxt', "@vuestic/nuxt", '@vueuse/nuxt', '@formkit/nuxt'],

    swiper: {
        prefix: 'Swiper',
        styleLang: 'css',
        modules: ['navigation', 'pagination', 'thumbs'],
    },

    vuestic: {
        config: {
            components: {
                VaCheckbox: {
                    iconColor: 'brand-icon',
                    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                    borderColor: '#D6D8DB',
                },
                VaSelect: {
                    iconColor: 'brand-icon',
                    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                    borderColor: '#D6D8DB',
                    borderRadius: '12px',
                },
                VaDatePicker: {
                    firstWeekDay: "Monday",
                    selectedText: '#FFFFFF',
                },
                VaButton: {
                    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                },
                presets: {
                    VaButton: {
                        pagination: {background: '#989EA5'},
                    }
                }
            },
            colors: {
                variables: {
                    'primary': '#B46B95',
                    'secondary': '#000000',
                    'focus': '#ffffff',
                    'backgroundElement': '#FFFFFF',
                    'textSelected': '#2F3132',
                    'starGray': '#E4E5E7',
                    'brand-icon': '#B46B95',
                    'background-primary': '#FFFFFF',
                    'pagination': '#989EA5'
                },
            },

            breakpoint: {
                enable: false,
                bodyClass: false,
            },
        }
    },
})
```

pacage.json

```
{
  "name": "nuxt-app",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nuxt": "3.3.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@formkit/nuxt": "^0.18.3",
    "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.4.11",
    "@types/node": "^20.4.4",
    "@vuestic/nuxt": "1.0.12",
    "@vueuse/nuxt": "9.12.0",
    "maska": "^2.1.9",
    "nuxt-swiper": "1.0.1",
    "pinia": "^2.1.4",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0"
  }
}
```

when I register in the nuxt.config.ts `ssr: false` then index.html it is being created, but I need to use ssr in my project. I tried to create app.html at the root of the directory, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Do you use catch-all routes in your project? If yes, then you would need to tell Nuxt which routes it needs to generate - see: https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/deployment#selective-pre-rendering